# Chapter Heading like Cambridge University Press

Tags: header-footer

Cambridge University Press uses the following types of chapter headings.[image]

How can I create the same fancy heading without using their codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility using `titlesec` and `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\tikz\node[
      font=\huge\bfseries\color{white},
      fill=gray!50,
      rounded corners=20pt,
      minimum height=1.6cm,
      text width=3em,
      align=center,
      inner xsep=0pt] {\parbox{1.5em}{\thechapter\hfill}};%
  }
  {-1em}
  {\tikz\node[
      fill=gray,
      font=\Large\sffamily\color{white},
      minimum height=1.6cm,
      text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax,
      align=center,inner xsep=0pt] {#1};%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\tikz\node[
      font=\huge\bfseries\color{white},
      fill=gray!50,
      rounded corners=20pt,
      minimum height=1.6cm,
      text width=3em,
      align=center,
      inner xsep=0pt] {\parbox{1.5em}{\mbox{}\hfill}};%
  }
  {-1em}
  {\tikz\node[
      fill=gray,
      font=\Large\sffamily\color{white},
      minimum height=1.6cm,
      text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax,
      align=center,
      inner xsep=0pt] {#1};%
  }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Tomaras-Tsamis-Woodard Solution}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An example for a starred chapter:

[image]

And for a numbered chapter:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, but there is a problem that I have elaborated below.

Comment: @Ome Please see my updated answer.